# dataframe: create DataFrame using two different dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have two different functions which has two different dictionaries. First, I have to merge to dictionaries into one and then connect two dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
output_df1 = {}
output_df1['diff_sum'] = 108
output_df1['cumsum'] = 232
out2 = {}
out2['carving'] = 1299
out2['bearing'] = 255
merge_dict = {**output_df1, **out2}
# upto this I'm able to do this
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df['tata'] = merge_dict
new_df['diff_sum'] = 108
new_df
```

Getting result

[image]

Want this

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame(merge_dict.values(), index=merge_dict, columns=["tata"])
print(new_df)
```

Prints:

```
          tata
diff_sum   108
cumsum     232
carving   1299
bearing    255
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just convert the `merge_dict` to dataframe directly by setting the index name to `'tata'` and then transposing it.

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(merge_dict, index=['tata']).T
```

```
In [27]: df2
Out[27]: 
          tata
diff_sum   108
cumsum     232
carving   1299
bearing    255
```

Comment: It will not work if ```['tata'] comes from another dict. like one_dict = {}
one_dict['trip'] = merge_dict```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `['tata'] comes from another dict` . But yeah I think I get the gist of it and the other solutions might be better in that context.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
output_df1 = {}
output_df1['diff_sum'] = 108
output_df1['cumsum'] = 232
out2 = {}
out2['carving'] = 1299
out2['bearing'] = 255
merge_dict = {**output_df1, **out2}
# upto this I'm able to do this
new_df = pd.DataFrame(merge_dict.values(),index=merge_dict.keys(),columns=['tata'])
new_df
```